# Sum of Geometric infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

How do I solve this:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(1-p)^{k-1}$$

I forgot how to do this, or the formula I need to use. Could not find it online for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{k\geq0}x^{k}=\frac{1}{1-x},\left|x\right|<1
 $$ hence taking the derivative $$\sum_{k\geq0}kx^{k-1}=\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}
 $$ then take $x=1-p$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a geometric series. However
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^{k}=\dfrac{1}{1-(1-p)}=\dfrac{1}{p}$$
provided $|1-p|<1$. This is an analytic function of $p$ in the disc of convergence, so it is allowed to differentiate term by term, which gives you the series you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Provided $0<p<2$, then we can write that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{k}=\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}=\frac1p$$
By taking the derivative with respect to $p$, we get 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(1-p)^{k-1}=\frac{1}{p^2}$$